# Add padding on either side of button

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add padding to either side of my button below, however, the padding I currently have is only affecting the text within the button itself.

Whenever I try to add padding for the entire button, it throws errors about me having more than one `padding`

How can I rectify?

```
final registerButton = Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
      color: Color(0xff33333D),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: mq.size.width / .2,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 10.0, 15.0),
        child: Text(
          "Sign Up",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
            color: Color(0xffffffff),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            User user =
                (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text,
              password: _passwordController.text,
            ))
                    .user;
            if (user != null) {
              user.updateProfile(displayName: _nameController.text);
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.home);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e); // when something is wrong, these reset every anwser
            _nameController.text = "";
            _passwordController.text = "";
            _repasswordController.text = "";
            _emailController.text = "";
            // TODO: alertdialog with error
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

Edit: Full Source Code

```
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _repasswordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mq = MediaQuery.of(context);

    final logo = Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/SignUp_Photo.jpg",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );

    final text = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(85.0, 0.0, 85.0, 5.0),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Sign Up",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                    color: Color(0xff33333D),
                    fontSize: 45,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );

final registerButton = Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
      color: Color(0xff33333D),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: mq.size.width / .2,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 10.0, 15.0),
        child: Text(
          "Sign Up",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
            color: Color(0xffffffff),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            User user =
                (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text,
              password: _passwordController.text,
            ))
                    .user;
            if (user != null) {
              user.updateProfile(displayName: _nameController.text);
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.home);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e); // when something is wrong, these reset every anwser
            _nameController.text = "";
            _passwordController.text = "";
            _repasswordController.text = "";
            _emailController.text = "";
            // TODO: alertdialog with error
          }
        },
      ),
    );

    final bottom = Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        registerButton,
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Terms and Conditions",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                    color: Color(0xff33333D),
                  ),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.authLogin);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Login",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                      color: Color(0xff33333D),
                    ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: mq.size.height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                logo,
                text,
                fields,
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
                  child: bottom,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the source code showing the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Thierry Added the source code

I originally added padding in my return scaffold at the end, but I have a photo at the top that I need without padding, and stuck to the top, so that method failed. The other items I am trying to get 35 padding on both sides. Question is only poised towards one, but I was going to carry over answer to the others

Comment: Your `Padding` widget should have a child, right ? See [Padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html)

Comment: I have tried that too, but the elements will only move up or down on padding, but not move away from the edges...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
final bottom = Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    registerButton,
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(9)),
    Row(...),
  ],
),
```

You probably want:

```
final bottom = Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    registerButton,
    const SizedBox(height: 9.0),
    Row(...),
  ],
),
```

If you want some space between your button and the next Row.

Or, maybe this:

```
final bottom = Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9)
      child: registerButton,
    ),
    Row(...),
  ],
),
```

if you want to add 9.0 padding all-around your button.

---

In your particular case:

[image]

```
final bottom = Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: registerButton,
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text(
            "Terms and Conditions",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                  color: Color(0xff33333D),
                ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "Login",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                    color: Color(0xff33333D),
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: It is from the edges I want the spacing, however. No matter what I seem to add, the items stay pinned to the edge

Comment: Check the second part of my answer. `Padding` widget applies padding to its child.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks! That works... Although you already answered the question, that fix only adds padding to the button, not the terms and conditions, or login. When I tried to add the padding as specified to both, nothing occurs. Any insight?

Comment: How do you add the padding to the term and conditions or login? `Padding(padding: [...], child: Text([...]),)` and `Padding(padding: [...], child: MaterialButton([...]),)`?

Answer (score 1):

'Padding' always gets added inside an element. Since your button has `Text` as its child, the padding gets added around the text. If you want space around your button, then what you are looking for is to add margin.

You can add margin to it by wrapping the button in a `Container` widget with a margin property inside.

```dart
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: //yourbutton
)
```